# SQLite: Conditional Where Clause depending on Row Existence

Tags: sqlite, select, where-clause

I have a fairly complex SQLite Query:

> select TDELIVER.ROWID, TDELIVER.DELSERN, COMSERNO, DELDATASRC, DELDATE,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 and PRODPALLET = 0 THEN DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 THEN DELEACTVOL ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfPalletsDelivered,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL < 0 THEN DELEACTVOL ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfPalletsCompensated,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI != 'CASE' and PRODCOMP != 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 THEN ROUND(DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE,0) ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfCasesDelivered,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI != 'CASE' and PRODCOMP != 1) and DELEACTVOL < 0 THEN DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfCasesCompensated,(select sum(DELEACTVOL * DELEPRICE) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) TotalPriceOfDelivery,

```
replace(group_concat(distinct TPGROUPS.PGRPVAL), ',', ', ') as Brands 
from TDELIVER 
inner join TDELENTR on TDELENTR.DELSERN=TDELIVER.DELSERN inner join  
LPROPGR on LPROPGR.PRODSERN=TDELENTR.PRODSERN inner join TPGROUPS on
TPGROUPS.PGRSERN= LPROPGR.PGRSERN 
where COMSERNO='501000000002118' and PGRPNAME COLLATE NOCASE in 
(select SETVALUE from TSETTING where SETKEY = 'ProductGroup')
GROUP BY TDELIVER.ROWID
```

This returns, among other things, a list of Brands.  However, sometimes, `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TSETTING WHERE SETKEY="ProductGroup" LIMIT 1);` will not return 1, and in that case I would like to run a simpler query:

> select TDELIVER.ROWID, TDELIVER.DELSERN, COMSERNO, DELDATASRC, DELDATE,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 and PRODPALLET = 0 THEN DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 THEN DELEACTVOL ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfPalletsDelivered,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI == 'CASE' or PRODCOMP == 1) and DELEACTVOL < 0 THEN DELEACTVOL ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfPalletsCompensated,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI != 'CASE' and PRODCOMP != 1) and DELEACTVOL > 0 THEN ROUND(DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE,0) ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfCasesDelivered,(select sum(CASE WHEN (DELEORDUNI != 'CASE' and PRODCOMP != 1) and DELEACTVOL < 0 THEN DELEACTVOL/PRODSIZE ELSE 0 END) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) NumberOfCasesCompensated,(select sum(DELEACTVOL * DELEPRICE) from TDELENTR inner join TPRODUCT on TDELENTR.PRODSERN=TPRODUCT.PRODSERN where DELSERN = TDELIVER.DELSERN) TotalPriceOfDelivery

```
from TDELIVER 
where COMSERNO='501000000002118'
```

(I used blockquotes to show the **identical code**, aside from the comma at the end of the first block)

My question is, how can I just run ONE query and have a column, 'Brands', returned with no data or an empty string in the row if `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TSETTING WHERE SETKEY="ProductGroup" LIMIT 1)` is false and the list of brands if it's true?

Some screenshots to help illustrate the question:

Simple Case:

[image: Simple Case]

Complex Case:

[image: Complex Case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute two different queries depending on a condition, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)
WHERE x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...)
WHERE NOT x;
```